# Settlement crack - is this one?

Tags: plaster, crack

Presently disagreeing with a letting agent responsible for a property I recently moved out of over a large wall crack. This crack was there (albeit smaller) when we took residence, and it has become worse over the tenancy period.

So far as we know we've done nothing to exacerbate the issue, but the agent and their contractor is adamant this is our fault: "... the crack is not settlement related. Basically the area of wall is made up of two sheets of plaster board and at the join the plaster board has been broken through ..."

[image: Crack]

I'd be grateful of any experienced opinions you might have - I appreciate it's not so easy to tell from a picture, but any guidance or background you might have would be useful both for myself in this situation and I suspect to others who experience similar.

Comment: Do they have any evidence supporting their argument? Looks structural to me. Did you document it when you moved in?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but in the center of the picture there are plaster spots that could be a previous attempt to fix the crack, but the patch also cracked.

Comment: Only the opinion of this contractor. The opening inventory lists 'some settlement cracking to LH wall' (the wall in question.

Comment: How does he suggest you exacerbated the crack?

Comment: From the vague plasterboard joint comment made in the agents email (listed in the question) and their dismissal of my point that there's no collateral damage to suggest any manor of firm impact, I think 'pressure on plasterboard joint' is their argument.

Comment: How much are they asking for?  It might just be prudent to pay a small amount and be done with it.  If you go to court, you lose, even if you win.

Comment: ~£250 quoted - not sure how good or bad that is? The principle is of equal concern.

Comment: Jeez... Fly me over and I'll fix it for $50

Comment: That's a bit much if it were in the US, but someone would have to return a few times to feather out the repair, and the whole wall would have to be painted, which they would have to do anyway. Easy DIY repair. Does look like it was repaired once, then got much worse. Don't know about settlement, but it is some sort of differential structural movement. Can't imagine how a tenant could do this. Something like ram a padded piano into the wall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one thing that doesn't make any sense based on the picture is this part:

> Basically the area of wall is made up of two sheets of plaster board and at the join the plaster board has been broken through

I'm not even sure it looks like this, but in any event, how exactly would you have cracked this without causing any other damage to the wall?  Like if you had banged the wall so hard as to crack a seam, you'd expect to see other damage to the wall.

Assuming these cracks do line up to the seam, two things come to mind. (1) The boards were not staggered properly and (2) The installer likely did not use paper or fiberglass tape on the seams - I think it looks more like a crummy installation.

At the end of the day though, this isn't really a serious issue, more of just wear and tear; all walls get banged up to some degree. The owner should just sand, patch and paint it and move on.

Comment: The 'z' shape the crack takes - does this correspond to the underlying boards shape?

Comment: @jstephenson no wallboard I've ever seen has a "z" shaped seam.

Comment: I agree, but I think what it might be is two boards next to each other that are offset by only a couple inches.  Vertical line is the seperation between two boards, as is the horizontal one

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem, my landlord said that our plaster was done 2 years ago , so it could be plaster settlement crack, and they will be sending the painters to assess the situation regarding the cracks.

I will suggest you to do the same, ask your landlord to send third party who can actually assess